# String parameter too long. retriving data from database to word template

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to retrieve some data from a table in sql database and FindandReplace in a word document. I am getting "string parameter too long" error at the WordApp.Selection.Find.Execute method.Please help!

private void btnML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        richTextBox2.Visible = true;
        this.btnML.Visible = true;



        String Template;

        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Management Letter";


        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Microsoft word Format (*.docx)|*.doc";


        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();


        NewFileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();

        Template = @"C:\Users\czu_ecu\Desktop\OAG-WORK\Management Letter Template_new.docx";

        CreateWordDocument(Template,
                       NewFileName);       

    }


    protected String Findings, Implication, Recommendation, ManagementComment, Person, CDate;




    private void CreateWordDocument(object fileName,
                                    object saveAs)
    {





        String sqlQueryfinding =  "Select [Findings_ID]  ,[AU_ID]  ,[Findings_No] ,[Findings_Title] ,[Findings_Rating]  ,[Findings_Description] ,[Findings_Implication] ,[Findings_Recomendation] ,[Findings_ManagementComment]  ,[Findings_ManagerResponsible] ,[Findings_CompletionDate] ,[FSC_ID]   ,[Findings_Status] from Findings Where AU_ID = 173";;    
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQueryfinding, Con.main_connect());

        //sqlData Reader Object to Read the Value returned from query
        SqlDataReader Dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //Set Missing Value parameter - used to represent
        // a missing value when calling methods through
        // interop.
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        //Setup the Word.Application class.


        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        //Setup our Word.Document class we'll use.
        Word.Document aDoc = null;


        // Check to see that file exists

        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

        object readOnly = false;
        object isVisible = false;

        //Set Word to be not visible.
        wordApp.Visible = false;

        //Open the word document

        aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing,
            false, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing);



        // Activate the document
        aDoc.Activate();

        while (Dr.Read())
        {

            // Find Place Holders and Replace them with Values.
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Finding>", Dr[3].ToString());
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<FindingDescription>", Dr[5].ToString());
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<ImplicationRating>", Dr[4].ToString());
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Recommendation>", Dr[7].ToString());
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<ManagementComment>", Dr[8].ToString());
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<ResponsiblePerson>", Dr[9].ToString());
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<CompletionDate>", Dr[10].ToString());
        }


        //Example of writing to the start of a document.
        // aDoc.Content.InsertBefore("This is at the beginning\r\n\r\n");

        //Example of writing to the end of a document.
        // aDoc.Content.InsertAfter("\r\n\r\nThis is at the end");


        //Save the document as the correct file name.


        try
        {

            aDoc.SaveAs(ref saveAs,
                     ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("Management Letter Created", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        //Close the document - you have to do this.
        aDoc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        CloseConnection();
        MessageBox.Show("Management Letter Created", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }





     private void FindAndReplace(Word.Application WordApp,
                               object findText,
                               object replaceWithText)
    {
        object matchCase = true;
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        object matchWildCards = false;
        object matchSoundsLike = false;
        object nmatchAllWordForms = false;
        object forward = true;
        object format = false;
        object matchKashida = false;
        object matchDiacritics = false;
        object matchAlefHamza = false;
        object matchControl = false;
        object read_only = false;
        object visible = true;
        object replace = 2;
        object wrap = 1;

        WordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(
            ref findText, 
            ref matchCase, 
            ref matchWholeWord, 
            ref matchWildCards, 
            ref matchSoundsLike,  
            ref nmatchAllWordForms, 
            ref forward, 
            ref wrap, 
            ref format, 
            ref replaceWithText, 
            ref replace, 
            ref matchKashida, 
            ref  matchDiacritics, 
            ref matchAlefHamza , ref matchControl);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

the replacement text is not allowed to longer than 255 when you do the replacement。
instead, you can select the text to be replaced, then change the selection text.

```
public static void ReplaceTextInWordDoc(Object findMe, Object replaceMe, ApplicationClass app)
{
    object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    app.Application.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
    app.Application.Selection.Find.Text = (string)findMe;
    app.Application.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();

    if (replaceMe.ToString().Length < 256) // Normal execution
    {
        app.Application.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = (string)replaceMe;
        app.Application.Selection.Find.Execute(
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    }
    else  // Some real simple logic!!
    {
        app.Application.Selection.Find.Execute(
        ref findMe, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        // the area where the findMe is located in the Document is selected.
        // Hence when you execute the statement below the replaceMe string is
        // placed in the area selected, which is what we wanted!

        app.Application.Selection.Text = (string)replaceMe;//****
    }
}
```

[Checkout Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4489ef80-8a0b-4881-bc5c-99db57656912/string-parameter-too-long-writing-to-a-word-doc-using-c?forum=vsto)

Comment: am i meant to replace the whole of FindAndReplace with this method (ReplaceTextInWordDoc)??

Comment: How do i pass a series of inputs and their outputs using this method.

Comment: I'm having an issue here... If I call this method a bunch of times, mostly the strings are shorter than 255 chars and it runs the `if`.  But once it catches one that goes to the `else`, none of the subsequent calls work properly.  Any idea on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

To complement Will Wu's answer - it has been slightly modified, and it's like it really worked out for me.

```
public static void ReplaceTextInWordDoc(Object findMe, Object replaceMe,   ApplicationClass app) {
    object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    app.Application.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
    app.Application.Selection.Find.Text = (string)findMe;
    app.Application.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();

    if (replaceMe.ToString().Length < 256) {
        app.Application.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = (string)replaceMe;
        app.Application.Selection.Find.Execute(
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    } else {
        //this cycle do replacing for EVERY example of 'findMe'text.
        while(app.Application.Selection.Find.Execute(
              ref findMe, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
              ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
              ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing)){

            app.Application.Selection.Text = (string)replaceMe;
            app.Application.Selection.Collapse();
        }
    }
}
```